# CSS font size change works but not reflected in WYSIWYG editor Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have made a font size and font color change in the CSS of my child theme and when I refresh pages on the site it works fine, but when I create a new post the WYSIWYG still has the default font size and color of the old one. I've tried searching for the answer to this problem and to see if it's also a settings option within Wordpress but can't find the solution.

Here is the styles I have added to the CSS:

```
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-size: 1.5rem !important;
    line-height: 1.375em;
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [Editor Style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style).

WordPress doesn't automatically include your theme's styles into the TinyMCE editor, but does allow you to do so with a bit of configuration.

**1) Specify theme support**

Your child theme should have a `functions.php` file. In that file, add:

```
add_editor_style();
```

**2) Add your CSS**

Create a file called `editor-style.css` in your child theme package, and add the CSS that you wish to apply to the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: thank you so much! That has worked perfectly! Much appreciated